# Highcharts async tooltip is drawn on top of point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to display a tooltip where the content is loaded asynchronously. The content loads fine, however the tooltip is drawn on top of the point, which can get very messy. 
How can I force the tooltip to be rendered either above or below the point?

My `formatter` function looks something like this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function (tooltip) {
        let text = 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                    '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>'

    // More text set asynchronously
    setTimeout(function () {
        tooltip.label.attr({
        text: text +
          '<br> more details here <br>' +
          'more details here <br>' +
          'more details here <br>' +
          'more details here <br>'
      });
    }, 5)

    return text
    }
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kvs4abh/2/) for a full example of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr` method also to change `y` tooltip position:

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        tooltip.label.attr({
            text: text +
                '<br> more details here <br>' +
              'more details here <br>' +
              'more details here <br>' +
              'more details here <br>',
            y: tooltip.now.y - 50
      });
    }, 2000)
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m14b7s6f/